# Split Text into Columns Function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have an excel spreadsheet with rows of data as shown below. There is a code with the product name and then a number.

```
QA32 Product One (Large) 23
AZ63 Product Two 96
PR65 Product Three 149
```

How do I split each field into a column?

I tried the "split text into columns" on excel using the delimited option and separating by spaces but the fact that some product names had more that one word caused the some numbers to be in the wrong column. E.g.,

```
Code     Name       Number       
QA32    Product      One       (Large)    23
AZ63    Product      Two         96
PR65    Product      Three       149
```

This is the desired result:

```
Code        Name                Number
QA32    Product One (Large)       23
AZ63    Product Two               96
PR65    Product Three             149
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/620533/sorting-excel-column-by-ip-address/620600#620600

Answer (score 2):

Use `FIND-function` to determine the position of your first and last space. After that, use the`MID-function` to split your data into three parts. If you know the position of your spaces, the splitting is easy. Finding the first space is also trivial since `FIND` goes from left to right. Unfortunatly, there is no way to tell Excel to search from right to left.

So the difficult part is, to determine the last space! Here we use an array formula.
To enter an array formula, you paste the formula into a cell and don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Instead you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
{=MAX((MID(A2,ROW(A:A),1)=" ")*ROW(A:A))}
```

If done successfully, Excel will append a starting and ending curly bracket.

---

Insert all formulas at the given cells and use `autofill down`

A2: your data goes here
B2:`=FIND(" ",A2,1)`
C2:`=MAX((MID(A2,ROW(A:A),1)=" ")*ROW(A:A))`  <-array formula!
D2:`=MID(A2,1,B2-1)`
E2:`=MID(A2,B2+1,C2-B2-1)`
F2:`=MID(A2,C2+1,LEN(A2))`

<sub>Result screen</sub>
[image]

Comment: `=MAX((MID(A2,ROW(A:A),1)=" ")*ROW(A:A)) <-array formula!` is a cool formula

Answer (score 0):

If a suitable algorithm is to return:

- Code = The first word
- Product = Everything between the first and last words
- Number = The last word

Then the following formulas should work.

Assume your data is in A1:

```
Code:     =LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))-1)
Product:  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),100,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)))-198))
Number:   =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```