# Finding IPs covered by Subnets in an Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, ip

I have a giant excel document that contains a list of IPs, but there are also entries that have subnets.  So for example, I might see "IP" "/16" and the first two octets would be the first two octets of the subnetted IP.  What I'm wondering is if there is any way with excel I can check if the first two octets of an IP MATCH one of the rows with an /16 subnet.  Basically I want to know if there is a way to find entries that override each other.  Ex 192.168.1.1 192.168.0.0 /16, the 192.168.1.1 would be highlighted red or whatever.  I know you would use an if, or at least I think, but I can't figure out how I would split the two octets and compare them, and also factor in the fact that the one it needs to be compared with has to have an "/16" in the same row.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if this makes no sense whatsoever, comment and I'll try to clarify.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorting Excel column by IP address:  http://superuser.com/questions/620533/sorting-excel-column-by-ip-address/620600#620600

Comment: Without zero-padding, writing formulas to handle IPs properly in Excel can be tricky. I was starting to come up with some fairly simple ideas, but they won't work right unless each octet is exactly three digits long.

Comment: Octets really have nothing to do with subnetting. The dotted-decimal notation using octets is simply to make IPv4 addresses easier for humans to read. Subnet boundaries can be inside an octet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do is to break up the IP into octets first.  Then you could use concatenate to rejoin octets 1 & 2.  From there you can use conditional formatting, vlookup or whatever method you like to compare the values.

I was looking for some guidance on manipulating IPs for a similar pet project and found the following article to be extremely useful.

http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/geeky-excel-formulas-subnet-math-group-by-subnet-using-built-in-excel-2010-formulas/

I found that the formula for the second octet was a little buggy, so I reworked it.

```
# Return Octet 1 of the IP in Cell A2
=LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)

# Return Octet 2 of the IP in Cell A2
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-1)

# Return Octet 3 of the IP in Cell A2
=LEFT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))),FIND(".",RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))))-1)

# Return Octet 4 of the IP in Cell A2
=RIGHT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))),(LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

=LEFT(A2,IFERROR(FIND(".",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"."," ",1)),"."," ",1)),0))

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off of David Kennedy's answer a little bit, say the subnet is in A2 formatted at 192.168.1.1/30 and only works from /32 through /24 subnets

```
First Octet   B2: =LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)
Second Octet  C2: =LEFT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-1)
Third Octet   D2: =LEFT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))),FIND(".",RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))))-1)
Fourth Octet  E2: =LEFT(RIGHT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))),(LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))))))),FIND("/",RIGHT(RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))),(LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))),LEN(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))))))))-1)
End of subnet F2: =E2+(2^(32-RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2))))-1
int version of first IP of subnet G2: =VALUE(CONCAT(TEXT(B2,0),TEXT(C2,"000"),TEXT(D2,"000"),TEXT(E2,"000")))
int version of last IP of subnet H2: =VALUE(CONCAT(TEXT(B2,0),TEXT(C2,"000"),TEXT(D2,"000"),TEXT(F2,"000")))
```

after that, you can compare the beginning to see if it falls into one of the listed subnets, easiest way would be the following A4 being your IP you want to check if its in a subnet formatted as 192.168.1.3 :

```
int of ip B4 : =VALUE(CONCATENATE(TEXT(MID(A4,1,FIND(".",A4,1)-1),"000"),TEXT(MID(A4,FIND(".",A4,1)+1,FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1))-FIND(".",A4,1)-1),"000"),TEXT(MID(A4,FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1))+1,FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1)))-FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1))-1),"000"),TEXT(MID(A4,FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1)))+1,FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1)))-FIND(".",A4,1+FIND(".",A4,1))+1),"000")))
If in subnet C4: =AND(B4>=G$2,B4<=H$2)
```

In this specific case I would check the first and last listed IP to see if it falls inside the octet at all

| 192.168.1.1/30 | 192 | 168 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 192168001001 | 192168001004 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 192.168.1.3 | 192168001003 | TRUE |  |  |  |  |  |
| 192.168.1.5 | 192168001005 | FALSE |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score -1):

Try this for fourth octet. 
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",REPT(" ",15)),15))

Comment: Please explain how this words.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.